# Adding one new project to an existing solution creates Solution configurations that need to be deleted

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with 144 projects and the only configurations are "Debug|ANSI Debug" and "Release|ANSI Release".

I added a unit test project and when I was preparing for checkin and comparing changes to the solution file, I found that "Debug|Any" and "Release|Any" had been added FOR EVERY PROJECT.
I need to go through this and remove ALL of the unwanted configurations now. I should not need to do this, adding a project should not create this pollution or make work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit each of the 144 projects individually. To remove the configurations that you don't want, use the Configuration Manager. From Visual Studio's Build menu choose 'Configuration Manager...'.

To remove 'Any', click the drop-down for 'Active Solution Platform' and choose '<edit...>'. Select 'Any' and click the remove button. This will update all projects.

For your new unit test project, find and adjust the platform for each of the possible configuration/platform combinations you want to keep.